# Table exists in PHPmyAdmin but does not appear using SHOW TABLES query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a new user to stackoverflow, I did do a search for similar questions and I found a many, but none were resolved in a way that helped me.  So that's why I'm asking this even though it may be a duplicate.  (This one for example seems to be the same problem I'm having: [MySQL table exists on server but cannot access it from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415065/mysql-table-exists-on-server-but-cannot-access-it-from-php))

I created a table (members) in my database (test) using PHPmyAdmin.  If I do an SQL query there to SHOW TABLES FROM test, the table "members" is listed.  However, PHP does not seem to be able to access it.  This is my file access_test_table.php:

```
<html>
<body>

Testing.<br>

<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

echo "The host is $host<br/>";
echo "The username is $username<br/>";
echo "The password is $password<br/>";
echo "The db name is $db_name<br/>";
echo "The table name is $tbl_name<br/>";

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
echo "<br/>";
}
else {
echo "Connected to database.<br/>";
}

//Want to show the tables in the database
$query_1="SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name'";
$result_q1 = mysqli_query($con,$query_1);

if (!mysqli_query($con,$query_1))
  {
  echo("Errorcode: " . mysqli_errno($con));
  echo "<br/>";
  }
else {
  echo "The following tables are in the database: " . $result_q1;
  echo "<br/>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
echo "Connection closed.";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked that "username" is the same user as was used to create the table and has the right permissions to access it.  I also updated to using no mysql_* commands but rather mysqli_* ones.  Finally, I tried using mysqli_multi_query, but the result is the same.  This is the output of the code on the page:

Testing.
The host is localhost
The username is username
The password is password
The db name is test
The table name is members
Connected to database.
Errorcode: 1064
Connection closed.

Can someone suggest to me how I can fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but you have an extra quote `'` in `$query_1="SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name'";` change it to `$query_1="SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name";` - That alone will cause an error.

Comment: I'm assuming your issue is just the syntax error mentioned in the above comment, but also make sure your "username" user has the relevant privileges to be able to use the `SHOW TABLES FROM ...` query. If the user doesn't have access to any of the tables, none of them will show up in the resultset

Comment: Hello, yep, I think it's the part with the extra quote.  I tried using the name of the db, instead of the variable that's holding it, and it works.  $query_1="SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name"; doesn't seem to work though.  However, $query_1="SHOW TABLES FROM " . $db_name; does.

Comment: How should I indicate that this is solved?

Comment: @RKD314 you could answer your own Question indicating this typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `'` from the Query:

```
$query_1="SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name'";
```

So it looks like this:

```
$query_1="SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name";
```

Credits to Fred (Posted as Community Wiki to close the Question)